# Retrieve Document content from Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve user data from a Firebase Collection.

This is what it looks like:
[image: Firebase]

This is the method I wrote to get the data:

```
static String getUserData(creatorId, keyword) {
 var documentName = Firestore.instance
     .collection('users')
     .document(creatorId)
     .get()
     .then((DocumentSnapshot) {
   String data = (DocumentSnapshot.data['$keyword'].toString());
   return data;
 });
}
```

The method only returns null. If I print the String in the Method it works. How can I return the String?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers Paul

Comment: It looks like you're caught by a common misunderstanding about deferred execution.  The return value from this function is null because the function doesn't return anything. It just assigns `documentName` to a future and returns.  This function must return a Future<String> and the caller must await it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `async` and `await` to be able to wait for the data to be fully retrieved and then you can return the data.

> The async and await keywords provide a declarative way to define asynchronous functions and use their results.

For example:

```
Future<String> getUserData(creatorId, keyword) async {
 var documentName = await Firestore.instance
     .collection('users')
     .document(creatorId)
     .get()
     .then((DocumentSnapshot) {
   String data = (DocumentSnapshot.data['$keyword'].toString());
   return data;
 });
}
```

And then you since `getUserData` returns a `Future`, you can use the `await` keyword to call it:

```
await getUserData(id, key);
```

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await